# NestJs Type Error - Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, repository, decorator

Suddenly i get an type error when using the InjectRepository decorator in NestJs. This error happens in every service.

```js
 constructor(
    private userRepository: UserRepository,

    @InjectRepository(Workout) <--- Error
    private workoutRepository: Repository<Workout>,
  ) {}
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

I get the following error:
**Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.ts(1239)**

I really don't know why this appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this lint error raised using `@Inject(forwardRef(() => Class))`.

It can be solved by updating `@nestjs/common` to `v9.3.0`.

Apparently, this was an issue introduced by TypeScript v5.
"[it] introduces some tightening on decorator type-checking."<sup>[1](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/10959)</sup>

How `Inject` worked:

```
export declare const Inject:
  (entity: Function) =>
    (target: object, key: string | symbol, index?: number) => void;

export class Foo {}

export class C {
  constructor(@Inject(Foo) x: any) {}
}
```

As you can see, `Inject` requires a second argument that's either a `symbol` or a `string`.

NestJS v9.3.0 has this solved under this merged PR: [Constructor parameter decorators should allow undefined as the type of key #10959](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/10959)