# @InjectRepository typescript error (Nestjs and typeorm)

Tags: nestjs

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Chat } from './entities/chat.entity';
import { Message } from './entities/message.entity';

export class ChatService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Chat) private chatRepo: Repository<Chat>,
        @InjectRepository(Message) private messagesRepo: Repository<Message>
    ) {}
    ...
```

I have not idea why I get this error:

> src/chat/chat.service.ts:14:4 - error TS1239: Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string | symbol'.
>
> 14   @InjectRepository(Chat) private chatRepo: Repository,
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/chat/chat.service.ts:15:4 - error TS1239: Unable to resolve
> signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string | symbol'.
>
> 15   @InjectRepository(Message) private messagesRepo:
> Repository

For example this is Chat.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Message } from './message.entity';

@Entity()
export class Chat {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Message, (a) => a.chat, {
        // cascade: true,
        // eager: true
    })
    messages: Message[];
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Which Nest and Typescript version do you have?

Comment: I've just found a solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76003019/nestjs-type-error-argument-of-type-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-parameter?rq=2

Despite I created project yesterday it had @nestjs/common in version 9.0.0. I guess it happend because I used template with pnpm